# About 4k video playing on browser

Tags: firefox, video, 4k-monitor

I am trying to play 4k video on Firefox. When I play it on VLC, it is smooth. Is there any GPU driver installation requirement on Firefox? Or plugins or extensions?

Comment: Go to "about:support" and in the "Graphics" section check whether it can use WebGL features or not.

Comment: WebGL 1 Driver Version 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.59 , this is there , bt after that its not working